# How to SELECT Records from MySQL That Has Any of Listed Terms

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'd like to SELECT (or UPDATE) from MySQL records by which some column `x` has any of the following terms:

```
introduction  
primer  
first course  
fundamentals  
essentials  
for Dummies
```

Data type of `x` is varchar.

Most of them are single-word terms. As long as they appear in the string in `x` it should be returned (or updated). Some of them are multi-word terms. In this case, all the words must appear together and in the same order but anywhere in the string.

How do I construct this SQL query? (or how do I use the phpMyAdmin GUI to get the same result?)

Comment: Take a look at the mysql documentation and learn about 1. the `LIKE` operator and 2. the `OR` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexp`:

```
where x regexp 'introduction|primer|first course|fundamentals|essentials|for Dummies'
```

The alternative is to use `like` with a bunch of `or`s:

```
where x like '%introduction%' or
      x like '%primer%' or
      . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

```
    UPDATE MyTable

    SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'SearchForThis', 'ReplaceWithThis')

    WHERE SomeOtherColumn LIKE '%PATTERN%'
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP question

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    mytable       
where   rec regexp '[[:<:]](introduction|primer|first course|fundamentals|essentials|for Dummies)[[:>:]]'
```

> [[:<:]], [[:>:]]
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and
>   end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters
>   that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word
>   character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an
>   underscore (_).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html